# Generating independent random variables

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to generate n *independent* uniform variables on [0,1]. I am not sure if `numpy.random.uniform(0,1,size=n)` is fine because nothing tells me that the data is independently generated.

Do I have instead to loop n times on `numpy.random.uniform(0,1,size=1)`? Do I have to do something with the seed?

Comment: These are independently generated. Well as independent as they can be given we only have pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Yes these are statistically independent values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function exactly as you wrote: `numpy.random.uniform(0,1,size=n)`. Do not loop.

From [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) "... any value within the given interval is equally likely to be drawn by uniform."  Each value is as independent as a computer can make them.

Setting a seed will create the same array of random numbers each time. This is useful for testing so you can get the same output each time, but if you want the array to be a new set of random numbers each time the function is called, don't set a seed.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.random.uniform(0,1,size=n)` generates values as independently as possible using an pseudo-random number generator.

If you're not convinced, you can check that using the size argument and a for loop will give you exactly the same results:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 5

np.random.seed(5)
print(np.random.uniform(0,1,size=n))

np.random.seed(5)
for _ in range(n):
    print(np.random.uniform(0,1))
```